# Rotate Outer N x N Square Array, while leaving inner square array unmoved

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

How can I rotate (or shift) a 2D square array but leave any elements that are not on the "border" of the array unmoved?

Example:

```
1  2  3  4
12 13 14 5
11 15 16 6
10  9  8 7
```

What I want:

```
12  1  2 3
11 13 14 4
10 15 16 5
 9  8  7 6
```

That was just an example. I need this to work on any square array of N width where 2 < N < 100

Comment: You can do it using four `for` loops, one for each border of your square.

Comment: Since you know what you want how about you just start with that - no transform needed.

Comment: That was just an example. I need this to work on any square array of N width where  2 < N < 100

Comment: This seems really really simple to me, it is just 4 loops.  Have your tried to do it where you know the size?

Comment: @Hogan if if seems simple, please show a simple implemented solution as an answer.

Comment: This was a fun little exercise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array is stored as a square .NET array of rank 2 the code is pretty simple mainly consisting of four loops - one for each edge:

```
var array = new [,] {
  {  1,  2,  3,  4,  5 },
  { 16, 17, 18, 19,  6 },
  { 15, 24, 25, 20,  7 },
  { 14, 23, 22, 21,  8 },
  { 13, 12, 11, 10,  9 }
};

// Rank = 2 and "square" and side length >= 2 checks removed for clarity.
var sideLength = array.GetLength(0);
// Save first element from top edge.
var element00 = array[0, 0];
// Rotate left edge.
for (var y = 1; y < sideLength; y += 1)
  array[y - 1, 0] = array[y, 0];
// Rotate bottom edge.
for (var x = 1; x < sideLength; x += 1)
  array[sideLength - 1, x - 1] = array[sideLength - 1, x];
// Rotate right edge.
for (var y = sideLength - 2; y >= 0; y -= 1)
  array[y + 1, sideLength - 1] = array[y, sideLength - 1];
// Rotate top edge.
for (var x = sideLength - 2; x > 0; x -= 1)
  array[0, x + 1] = array[0, x];
// Put saved element in place.
array[0, 1] = element00;
```

Now the original array has been rotated as described in the question.

If the array is stored as a one dimensional array it is easier to create a class to perform the rotation. This class can store properties (the array and the side length) that can be used across method calls to simplify the code.

The four loops contains the same logic even though they look different:

```
class ArrayRotator<T> {

  public ArrayRotator(T[] array) {
    if (array == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("array");
    var sideLength = (Int32) Math.Sqrt(array.Length);
    if (sideLength*sideLength != array.Length)
      throw new ArgumentException("Not a square.", "array");
    Array = array;
    SideLength = sideLength;
  }

  public T[] Array { get; private set; }

  public Int32 SideLength { get; private set; }

  public void RotateArray() {
    if (SideLength < 3)
      return;
    // Save first element from top edge.
    var element00 = Array[0];
    // Rotate left edge.
    for (var y = 1; y < SideLength; y += 1)
      CopyElement(0, y, 0, y - 1);
    // Rotate bottom edge.
    for (var x = 1; x < SideLength; x += 1)
      CopyElement(x, SideLength - 1, x - 1, SideLength - 1);
    // Rotate right edge.
    for (var y = SideLength - 2; y >= 0; y -= 1)
      CopyElement(SideLength - 1, y, SideLength - 1, y + 1);
    // Rotate top edge.
    for (var x = SideLength - 2; x > 0; x -= 1)
      CopyElement(x, 0, x + 1, 0);
    // Put saved element in place.
    Array[1] = element00;
  }

  void CopyElement(Int32 x1, Int32 y1, Int32 x2, Int32 y2) {
    Array[GetIndex(x2, y2)] = Array[GetIndex(x1, y1)];
  }

  Int32 GetIndex(Int32 x, Int32 y) {
    return y*SideLength + x;
  }

}
```

Here is how to use the class:

```
var array = new [] {
   1,  2,  3,  4,
  12, 13, 14,  5,
  11, 15, 16,  6,
  10,  9,  8,  7
};
var arrayRotator = new ArrayRotator<Int32>(array);
arrayRotator.RotateArray();
```

Now the original array has been rotated as described in the question.

Comment: I assumed that the data was stored in n nested arrays of length n.  Is it common practice to flatten that out into a single array where segments of length sqrt(length) represent a "slice"?

Comment: @saarrrr: I don't know about common practice so I just made an assumption because the underlying data structure is not stated in the question. .NET also has "real" N dimensional arrays and that is actually the most natural representation.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question pretty interesting and fun, I've devised a little solution that works as long as the array conforms to a perfect square, this should work regardless of the side length.

NOTE: this is not the most optimized solution (I'm keen to try and make a more elegant solution, but this should suffice for now).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ArraySquareRotation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] arr = new int[]
            {
                1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3,
                12, 13, 14, 5, 6, 1,
                11, 15, 16, 6, 7, 22,
                10, 9, 8, 7, 8, 30,
                11, 15, 16, 6, 7, 22,
                1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3
            };


            // detect array size
            int size = arr.Length;

            // calculate the side length of the array (in terms of index)
            int sideLength = BruteForceSquareDimensions(size);

            // find the start of the last side of the square
            int lastRowStartIndex = size - sideLength;

            // a placeholder for us to generate a shifted array
            int[] arrRotated = new int[size];


            Console.WriteLine("Detected square with side length {0}", sideLength);
            Console.WriteLine();

            for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
            {
                // side rotation
                if ((i % sideLength) == 0 && i != size)
                {
                    // is multiple of
                    // right hand side, shift down
                    arrRotated[i + sideLength - 1] = arr[i - 1];

                    // left hand side, shift up
                    arrRotated[i + sideLength - (sideLength * 2)] = arr[i];
                } else if (i < sideLength)
                {
                    int lastRowIndex = sideLength * (sideLength - 1);

                    // first row, shift right
                    arrRotated[i] = arr[i - 1];

                    // last row, shit left
                    arrRotated[i + lastRowIndex - 1] = arr[i + lastRowStartIndex];
                } else if(i < lastRowStartIndex)
                {
                    // the inner square (this case may need some work)
                    arrRotated[i - 1] = arr[i - 1];
                }

            }            

            Console.WriteLine("Printing original array");
            Console.WriteLine("======================");
            PrintSquareArray(arr);

            Console.WriteLine();


            Console.WriteLine("Printing Shifted array");
            Console.WriteLine("======================");
            PrintSquareArray(arrRotated);

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// there is definately a better way.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="size"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        static int BruteForceSquareDimensions(int size)
        {

            int sideLength = 0;

            for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
            {
                if ((i * i) == size)
                {
                    sideLength = i;
                }
            }

            return sideLength;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method just prints the array in the desired readable format
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="arr"></param>
        static void PrintSquareArray(int[] arr)
        {
            int size = arr.Length;
            int sideLength = BruteForceSquareDimensions(size);

            for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
            {
                if ((i % sideLength) == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(arr[i - 1]);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(arr[i - 1] + "\t");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The output should look as follows (Square):**

```
Detected square with side length 4

Printing original array
======================
1       2       3       4
12      13      14      5
11      15      16      6
10      9       8       7

Printing Shifted array
======================
12      1       2       3
11      13      14      4
10      15      16      5
9       8       7       6
Press any key to exit
```

And here's a 6 by 6

```
Detected square with side length 6

Printing original array
======================
1       2       3       4       5       3
12      13      14      5       6       1
11      15      16      6       7       22
10      9       8       7       8       30
11      15      16      6       7       22
1       2       3       4       5       3

Printing Shifted array
======================
12      1       2       3       4       5
11      13      14      5       6       3
10      15      16      6       7       1
11      9       8       7       8       22
1       15      16      6       7       30
2       3       4       5       3       22
Press any key to exit
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I got.  Tested on the 4x4 you provided and the following 5x5 square array.  Also, I am assuming the data is stored in jagged arrays, such that 1 array contains n arrays each of length n.

```
1       2       3       4       5
16      17      18      19      6
15      24      25      20      7
14      23      22      21      8
13      12      11      10      9

static int[][] Transform(int[][] old)
{
    var maxIdx = old.Length-1;
    var canvas = new List<int[]>();

    //top border
    var top = new List<int>();
    top.Add(old[1][0]);
    for (var i = 0; i < maxIdx; i++)
    {
        top.Add(old[0][i]);
    }

    //bottom border
    var bottom = new List<int>();
    for (var i = 1; i < maxIdx+1; i++)
    {
        bottom.Add(old[maxIdx][i]);
    }
    bottom.Add(old[maxIdx - 1][maxIdx]);

    //middle
    var middle = new List<int[]>();
    for (var i = 1; i < maxIdx; i++) //for each inner array
    {
        var inside = new List<int>();
        inside.Add(old[i + 1][0]);
        for (var j = 1; j < maxIdx; j++)
        {
            inside.Add(old[i][j]);
        }
        inside.Add(old[i - 1][maxIdx]);
        middle.Add(inside.ToArray());
    }

    //Rebuild
    canvas.Add(top.ToArray());
    foreach (var arr in middle)
    {
        canvas.Add(arr);
    }
    canvas.Add(bottom.ToArray());
    return canvas.ToArray();
}
```